# Silverlight ValidationSummary not handling ValidationException

Tags: validation, silverlight-4.0, observablecollection

I have a dataform and a datagrid in the dataform. this datagrid is bound to an ObservableCollection. I have written a CustomValidator that throws ValidationException when the count in the observable collection is 0. ValidationSummary control doesn't handle this exception, instead the application becomes unstable and calls Application Unhandled  Exception. I am not using RIA services. Below is my code

```
public class UserCompanyProgram : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void ToWebServiceProgram()
    {
        lstUserProgram.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //Validator.ValidateProperty(lstUserProgram,
            //             new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "lstUserProgram" });
            lstUserProgram = _lstUserProgram;
            UserProgramChanged();
        };
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Pricing.Model.UserProgram> _lstUserProgram = new ObservableCollection<UserProgram>();
    [CustomValidation(typeof(ModelValidator), "ValidateUserProgramCollection")]
    [Display(Name = "New Programs", Description = "Add program")]
    public ObservableCollection<UserProgram> lstUserProgram
    {
        get { return _lstUserProgram; }
        set
        {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(lstUserProgram,
                new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "lstUserProgram" });
                this._lstUserProgram = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("lstUserProgram");

        }
    }
}

  dgSelectedPrograms.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("lstUserProgram") { ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true });
```

How do I make the ValidationSummary handle the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my project where I was forcing the validation on the keyup event of the textbox.  I was setting the textbox bound property to the text from the textbox, on the keyup event, so I could validate as they typed.  Silverlight does not like this.  It was throwing an unhandled exception.  So once I removed the validation from the keyup event, it worked as it should.  The property does not get updated until the user selects another control on the screen, but if I want to take advantage of the Silverlight validation, that's what needs to be done.

I have not worked with validating a collection such as what you're doing, but maybe in cases like that you need to use the IDataErrorInfo implementation.  An exception doesn't get thrown in that case, so that is probably the way to go.